# simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 18632: parser error : Specification mandates value for attribute

Tags: php, 1с

Пытаюсь сделать выгрузку Номенклатуры с 1C Предприятие

От 1C получаю фаил и с помощью `simplexml_load_string` разбираю

При маленьком наличии Номенклатуры все отлично работало, сейчас добавили свыше 300 товаров и вышла ошибка - `local.ERROR: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 18632: parser error : Specification mandates value for attribute Между {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0)`

Получаемый xml фаил проверял, полностью валидный, все теги закрыты

Похоже на какой-то лимит, как будто при чтении xml обрезается

Строка `18632` обрезается

```
            <Предложение>
                <Ид>f9ac95b1-9b4a-11eb-ba99-a85e45e</Ид>
                <Артикул/>
                <Наименование>Труба проф. 25*25*2 L-3m</Наименование>
                <БазоваяЕдиница Код="796 " НаименованиеПолное="Штука" МеждународноеСокращение="PCE">
                    <Пересчет>
                        <Единица>796</Единица>
                        <Коэффициент>1</Коэффициент>
                    </Пересчет>
                </БазоваяЕдиница>
                <Цены>
                    <Цена>
                        <Представление> 0 руб. за PCE</Представление>
                        <ИдТипаЦены>b9c2c4f0-9918-11eb-ba99-a85e</ИдТипаЦены>
                        <ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>0</ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>
                        <Валюта>руб</Валюта>
                        <Единица>PCE</Единица>
                        <Коэффициент>1</Коэффициент>
                    </Цена>
                </Цены>
                <Количество>0</Количество>
                <Склад ИдСклада="7fc696d3-32d6-11e8-838a-d5a97e2" КоличествоНаСкладе="0"/>
                <Склад ИдСклада="cd424e13-8d4f-11eb-ba8c-a85e45e" КоличествоНаСкладе="0"/>
            </Предложение>
            <Предложение>
                <Ид>5295c8eb-9b4b-11eb-ba99-a85e45e</Ид>
                <Артикул/>
                <Наименование>Си плита 40*620*970</Наименование>
--18632--       <БазоваяЕдиница Код="796 " НаименованиеПолное="Штука" Между? 
local.ERROR: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 18632: parser error : Specification mandates value for attribute Между {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 18632: parser error : Specification mandates value for attribute Между at CatalogController.php:510)
```

Отрывок xml файла

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<КоммерческаяИнформация xmlns="urn:1C.ru:commerceml_2" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ВерсияСхемы="2.07" ДатаФормирования="2021-04-13T09:23:11">
    <Классификатор>
        <Ид>ид</Ид>
        <Наименование>Классификатор</Наименование>
        <Владелец>
            <Ид>ид</Ид>
            <Наименование>название</Наименование>
            <ОфициальноеНаименование>название</ОфициальноеНаименование>
            <ИНН>инн</ИНН>
            <КПП>кпп</КПП>
            <ОКПО/>
        </Владелец>
    </Классификатор>
    <ПакетПредложений СодержитТолькоИзменения="false">
        <Ид>ид</Ид>
        <Наименование>Пакет предложений</Наименование>
        <ИдКаталога>ид</ИдКаталога>
        <ИдКлассификатора>ид</ИдКлассификатора>
        <Владелец>
            <Ид>иид</Ид>
            <Наименование>название</Наименование>
            <ОфициальноеНаименование>название</ОфициальноеНаименование>
            <ИНН>инн</ИНН>
            <КПП>кпп</КПП>
            <ОКПО/>
        </Владелец>
        <ТипыЦен>
            <ТипЦены>
                <Ид>ид</Ид>
                <Наименование>Розничные + сайт</Наименование>
                <Валюта>руб</Валюта>
                <Налог>
                    <Наименование>НДС</Наименование>
                    <УчтеноВСумме>false</УчтеноВСумме>
                    <Акциз>false</Акциз>
                </Налог>
            </ТипЦены>
        </ТипыЦен>
        <Склады>
            <Склад>
                <Ид>ид</Ид>
                <Наименование>название</Наименование>
            </Склад>
            <Склад>
                <Ид>ид</Ид>
                <Наименование>название</Наименование>
            </Склад>
        </Склады>
        <Предложения>
            <Предложение>
                <Ид>f9ac95b1-9b4a-11eb-ba99-a85e45e</Ид>
                <Артикул/>
                <Наименование>Труба</Наименование>
                <БазоваяЕдиница Код="796 " НаименованиеПолное="Штука" МеждународноеСокращение="PCE">
                    <Пересчет>
                        <Единица>796</Единица>
                        <Коэффициент>1</Коэффициент>
                    </Пересчет>
                </БазоваяЕдиница>
                <Цены>
                    <Цена>
                        <Представление> 0 руб. за PCE</Представление>
                        <ИдТипаЦены>b9c2c4f0-9918-11eb-ba99-a85e45e</ИдТипаЦены>
                        <ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>0</ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>
                        <Валюта>руб</Валюта>
                        <Единица>PCE</Единица>
                        <Коэффициент>1</Коэффициент>
                    </Цена>
                </Цены>
                <Количество>0</Количество>
                <Склад ИдСклада="7fc696d3-32d6-11e8-838a-d5a97e2" КоличествоНаСкладе="0"/>
                <Склад ИдСклада="cd424e13-8d4f-11eb-ba8c-a85e45e" КоличествоНаСкладе="0"/>
            </Предложение>
            <Предложение>
                <Ид>5295c8eb-9b4b-11eb-ba99-a85e45e</Ид>
                <Артикул/>
                <Наименование>Си плита 40*620*970</Наименование>
                <БазоваяЕдиница Код="796 " НаименованиеПолное="Штука" МеждународноеСокращение="PCE"> -- строка 18632
                    <Пересчет>
                        <Единица>796</Единица>
                        <Коэффициент>1</Коэффициент>
                    </Пересчет>
                </БазоваяЕдиница>
                <Цены>
                    <Цена>
                        <Представление> 0 руб. за PCE</Представление>
                        <ИдТипаЦены>b9c2c4f0-9918-11eb-ba99-a85e45e</ИдТипаЦены>
                        <ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>0</ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>
                        <Валюта>руб</Валюта>
                        <Единица>PCE</Единица>
                        <Коэффициент>1</Коэффициент>
                    </Цена>
                </Цены>
                <Количество>0</Количество>
                <Склад ИдСклада="7fc696d3-32d6-11e8-838a-d5a97e2" КоличествоНаСкладе="0"/>
                <Склад ИдСклада="cd424e13-8d4f-11eb-ba8c-a85e45e" КоличествоНаСкладе="0"/>
            </Предложение>
            <Предложение>
                <Ид>6a40678b-9b4b-11eb-ba99-a85e45e</Ид>
                <Артикул/>
                <Наименование>Си плита 16*350*590</Наименование>
                <БазоваяЕдиница Код="796 " НаименованиеПолное="Штука" МеждународноеСокращение="PCE">
                    <Пересчет>
                        <Единица>796</Единица>
                        <Коэффициент>1</Коэффициент>
                    </Пересчет>
                </БазоваяЕдиница>
                <Цены>
                    <Цена>
                        <Представление> 0 руб. за PCE</Представление>
                        <ИдТипаЦены>b9c2c4f0-9918-11eb-ba99-a85e45e</ИдТипаЦены>
                        <ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>0</ЦенаЗаЕдиницу>
                        <Валюта>руб</Валюта>
                        <Единица>PCE</Единица>
                        <Коэффициент>1</Коэффициент>
                    </Цена>
                </Цены>
                <Количество>0</Количество>
                <Склад ИдСклада="7fc696d3-32d6-11e8-838a-d5a97e2" КоличествоНаСкладе="0"/>
                <Склад ИдСклада="cd424e13-8d4f-11eb-ba8c-a85e45e" КоличествоНаСкладе="0"/>
            </Предложение>
        </Предложения>
    </ПакетПредложений>
</КоммерческаяИнформация>
```

Comment: выложи полный xml 1-2 товаров, а не этот обрезок

Comment: желательно чтобы туда попал этот товар f9ac95b1-9b4a-11eb-ba99-a85e45e

Comment: @Jean-Claude Дополнил вопрос примером xml с товарами до и после ошибки

Comment: А simplexml_load_file() дает аналогичный результат? По предоставленному фрагменту ошибка не воспроизводится.
`$xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);`

Comment: хз, ошибка не воспроизводится, как вариант читай меньшими блоками

Comment: 3 секунды гугления https://forum.mista.ru/topic.php?id=705021